# Loading form data with Ajax, Now need to submit form data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have been looking for awhile to get this to work. (5 days) So I load pages through my site in the same div with ajax with next and back buttons. All the div information is form data. I need to add a jquery ajax function to take form data and submit to my php file for processing. Keep in mind the form data is new every time the button is clicked. Question is how to place the ajax function with the proper event handler and getting it send to php before the other ajax call reloads a different form.

**Loaded Form(there are many forms)**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="pages/student_info/ps1.php">
   <fieldset>

    <legend>Legal Name</legend>
    <label for='firstname'>First Name: </label>
    <input type='text' name='firstname' 
     id='firstname'minlength="2"required/>
    <br>
    <label for='lastname'>Last Name: </label>
    <input type='text' name='last-name' id='last-name' required/>
    <br>
    <label for='mi'>Middle Initial: </label>
    <input type='text' name='mi' id='mi' />
    <br>
    <br>
    <legend>Gender</legend>
    <label for="studentmale">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="studentgender" id="male" value="M" required/>
    <br>
    <label for="studentfemale">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="studentgender" id="female" value="F">
    <br>

   </fieldset>
  </form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
      //submit form with button click
      $("#next").click(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit();
        });


      $("#myForm").on( "submit", "form", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('#myForm').attr("action"),
            data: $('#myForm').serializeArray(), // getting filed value in 
             serialize form

            })
            .done(function(data){ // if getting done then call.

            // show the response
            alert(data);

            })
            .fail(function() { // if fail then getting message

            // just in case posting your form failed
            alert( "Posting failed." );

            });

            // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
            return false;

      });
```

**function for page navigation runs before i can stop for form injection**

```
         //This code runs when a back or next button has been pressed
        $("#next, #prev").click(function(){
          var max =$('#next').data("max");
          max = parseInt(max);
          currentPage = ($(this).attr('id')=='next') ? currentPage + 1 : 
            currentPage - 1;
          // ALL DATA VALIDATION DONE ON THIS ONE LINE
          var formStatus = $('#myForm').validate().form();

           ...much more code here but it all runs navigation just fine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delegation on this line is incorrect:

```
$("#myForm").on( "submit", "form", function(e) {
```

It is looking for a form *inside* `#myForm` but `myForm` is the form. ALso since you say you replace the whole form that listener will be lost on replacement

Delegate to a higher level ancestor that always exists and target `#myForm`

```
$(document).on( "submit", "#myForm", function(e) {
```

Comment: Ok tried that and the code block does run but now in chrome it says e is not defined, url is not defined and data not defined

Comment: Not sure why...code shown appears correct. Unless for some reason there is another `#myForm` in page

Comment: Double checked there is no other id with this name..only one. and on the call stack it has the appropriate values

Comment: Hard to help without a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: scripts are found in myScripts folder off root directory

Comment: I only get alert "post failed" but no errors thrown

Comment: You are correct, no errors are thrown. I am trying to input the data to the php file found on the action attribute of the #myForm div but when trying to attain it in the script, the debuger in chome shows that "url is not defined" this is also true for the data: on line 22 of the scripts page that is trying to get my data from the form "Data is not defined"

Comment: OK...go to your dev tools network tab. Inspect the actual request Data gets sent fine but response is error output html and starts *" Call to undefined function cleanWord()"* then gives you the php line number

Comment: Thank you sir! Days of hell solved. First time using stack overflow. I appreciate your response!